# Ansi C, Multithreading MatrixMultiplication

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix-multiplication

I have been programming this multiplethreaded matrix multiplication.
Somehow the programm works, but it does not give me the values of the result matrix.
Here it is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int rowA, rowB, colA, colB;
int myNrThreads = 0;
double **matrixA, **matrixB, **matrixOut;

void *multiplyThread (void *param);
void fillAndCheckMatrice(double **matrix, FILE *myFile, int row, int column) {
    char *line = NULL; 
    char *p;
    ssize_t read;
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    size_t length = 0; 

    getline (&line, &length, myFile);
    p = strtok(line, " ");
    row = atoi(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    column = atoi(p);
    printf("%d, %d\n", row, column);

    matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(double*));
    for (j = 0; j < row; ++j) {
        matrix[j] = malloc(column * sizeof(double));
    }
    i = 0;
    while ((read = getline (&line, &length, myFile)) != -1) {
        j = 0;
        p = strtok(line, " ");
        while (p != NULL) {
            matrix[i][j] = atof(p);
            ++j;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
             }
        ++i;
         }

    free(line);


}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t *myThread;
    int counter, j, r;
    FILE *fileA = fopen("matrixA.txt", "r");
    FILE *fileB = fopen ("matrixB.txt", "r");
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s number_of_threads\n",argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    myNrThreads = (atoi)(argv[1]);
    fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixA, fileA, rowA, colA);
    fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixB, fileB, rowB, colB);

    matrixOut = malloc(rowA * sizeof(double*));
    for (counter = 0; counter < rowA; ++counter) {
        matrixOut[counter] = malloc (colB * sizeof(double));
    }
    myThread = malloc(myNrThreads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    for (counter = 1; counter < myNrThreads; ++counter) {
        r = pthread_create (&myThread[counter], NULL, multiplyThread, (void*)counter);
        if (r != 0  ) {
            printf ("No threads create!");
            free (myThread);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    multiplyThread(0);
    for (counter = 1; counter < myNrThreads; ++counter) {
        pthread_join(myThread[counter], NULL);
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < rowA; ++counter) {
        for (j = 0; j < colB; ++j) {
            printf ("%.5f ", matrixOut[counter][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fileA);
    fclose(fileB);
    free(myThread);
    free(matrixA);
    free(matrixB);
    free(matrixOut);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * The method gets on the first line the dimensions of the matrice.
 * While filling every postion of our matrice, we control
 * if the given dimensions are the real dimensions of the matrice.
 * Everything is read from the .txt file, produced from our python
 * generator.
 * 
 */
void *multiplyThread(void *param){
    int myParam = (int)param;
    int limitBegin = (myParam * rowA) / myNrThreads;
    int limitEnd = ((myParam + 1) * rowA) / myNrThreads;
    int counterI, counterJ, counterK;
    for (counterI = limitBegin; counterI < rowA; ++counterI) {
        for (counterJ = 0; counterJ < colB; ++counterJ) {
            matrixOut[counterI][counterJ] = 0;
            for (counterK = 0; counterK < rowB; ++counterK) {
                matrixOut[counterI][counterJ] +=matrixA[counterI][counterK] * matrixB[counterK][counterJ];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("finished slice %d\n", myParam);
    return 0;

}
```

Any idea why???
Thanx in advance.
PS: at the pthread_create I get a warning at (void*)counter btw
EDIT:
matrixA and matrixB are given through matrixA.txt and matrixB.txt. They are read and the values are taken from that.
One of the txt file would look like this:
2 2 // The dimensions of the matrice
12 14
13 15

EDIT3: The new one. Here I get segmentation fault 11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void *multiplyThread (void *param);

int      rowA, rowB, colA, colB;
int      myNrThreads = 0;
double **matrixA, **matrixB, **matrixOut;

void fillAndCheckMatrice(double **matrix, FILE *myFile, int ID) {
    char *line = NULL; 
    char *p;
    int row, column;
    ssize_t read;
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    size_t length = 0; 

    getline (&line, &length, myFile);
    p = strtok(line, " ");
    row = atoi(p);

    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    column = atoi(p);
    printf("%d, %d\n", row, column);
    if (ID == 1) {
        rowA = row;
        colA = column;
    } else if (ID == 2) {
        rowB = row;
        colB = column;
    }
    matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(double*));
    for (j = 0; j < row; ++j) {
        matrix[j] = malloc(column * sizeof(double));
    }
    i = 0;
    while ((read = getline (&line, &length, myFile)) != -1) {
        j = 0;
        p = strtok(line, " ");
        while (p != NULL) {
            matrix[i][j] = atof(p);
            ++j;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
             }
        ++i;
         }

    free(line);


}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t *myThread;
    int counter, j, r;
    FILE *fileA = fopen("matrixA.txt", "r");
    FILE *fileB = fopen ("matrixB.txt", "r");
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s number_of_threads\n",argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    myNrThreads = (atoi)(argv[1]);
    fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixA, fileA, 1);
    fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixB, fileB, 2);

    matrixOut = malloc(rowA * sizeof(double*));
    for (counter = 0; counter < rowA; ++counter) {
        matrixOut[counter] = malloc (colB * sizeof(double));
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < rowA; ++counter) {
        for (j = 0; j < colB; ++j) {
            printf ("%.5f ", matrixOut[counter][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    myThread = malloc(myNrThreads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    for (counter = 1; counter < myNrThreads; ++counter) {
        printf("%d", counter);
        if (pthread_create (&myThread[counter], NULL, multiplyThread, (void*)(intptr_t)counter) != 0) {
            printf ("No threads create!");
            free (myThread);
            exit(-1);

        }
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < rowA; ++counter) {
        for (j = 0; j < colB; ++j) {
            printf ("%.5f ", matrixA[counter][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    multiplyThread(0);
    for (counter = 1; counter < myNrThreads; ++counter) {
        pthread_join(myThread[counter], NULL);
    }

    fclose(fileA);
    fclose(fileB);
    free(myThread);
    free(matrixA);
    free(matrixB);
    free(matrixOut);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * The method gets on the first line the dimensions of the matrice.
 * While filling every postion of our matrice, we control
 * if the given dimensions are the real dimensions of the matrice.
 * Everything is read from the .txt file, produced from our python
 * generator.
 * 
 */
void *multiplyThread(void *param){
    int myParam = (int)param;
    int limitBegin = (myParam * rowA) / myNrThreads;
    int limitEnd = ((myParam + 1) * rowA) / myNrThreads;
    int counterI, counterJ, counterK;
    for (counterI = limitBegin; counterI < rowA; ++counterI) {
        for (counterJ = 0; counterJ < colB; ++counterJ) {
            matrixOut[counterI][counterJ] = 0;
            for (counterK = 0; counterK < rowB; ++counterK) {
                matrixOut[counterI][counterJ] +=matrixA[counterI][counterK] * matrixB[counterK][counterJ];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("finished slice %d\n", myParam);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: multiplyThread doesn't use limitEnd (`counterI < rowA`???)

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this code, but what does this line do: `matrixOut = malloc(rowA * sizeof(double*));` .. `rowA` is never set anywhere in this code and why are you trying to get the `sizeof` a pointer to a `double` (vs. `sizeof(double)`)?

Comment: Can you please explain it

Comment: I think sizeof(double*) is ok since it's array of pointers. `rowA` indeed has no any value (it is passed into `fillAndCheckMatrix` by value).

Comment: @Inspired I have checked that part. rowA gets the value

Comment: Can you tell me the line of code where `rowA` gets a value?

Comment: @txtechhelp As I understand it: OP first allocates an array of `rowA` pointers to double (`rowA*sizeof(double*)`), then for each pointer he allocates an array of `colB` doubles (`colB*sizeof(double)`). I don't see any problem here (if rowA and colB would be initialized with proper values of course). I agree that having `rowA*colB*sizeof(double)` could be more straightforward, but then one can't write two indexes as `matrix[i][j]`.

Comment: @txtechhelp and what about the threading? that should work right?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems in the question code.  Perhaps the best 'answer' would be to carefully walk through the code and point out some of the issues.

---

First, consider the following:

```
int rowA, rowB, colA, colB;
```

Nothing really wrong with the above line, until (later in main):

```
fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixA, fileA, rowA, colA);
fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixB, fileB, rowB, colB);
```

The above lines pass the 'values' of 'rowA', 'colA' 'rowB' and 'colB'.  Being that these variables have no established values, it is obvious that there is trouble in the code.

Most likely, the intention is to initialize these values inside the 'fillAndCheckMatrice()' function.  However, in order to initialize these variables, the 'address' of the variables must be passed into 'fillAndCheckMatrice()', (not their 'values').  Perhaps something like this:

```
fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixA, fileA, &rowA, &colA);
fillAndCheckMatrice(matrixB, fileB, &rowB, &colB);
```

Then, of course, the 'fillAndCheckMatrice()' will have to be modified as well; from:

```
void fillAndCheckMatrice(double **matrix, FILE *myFile, int row, int column) {
```

To:

```
void fillAndCheckMatrice(double **matrix, FILE *myFile, int *row, int *column) {
```

And then, of course, every reference to 'row' and 'column' will now have to deal with a pointer to a variable, instead of the variable value.  Hence these:

```
row = atoi(p);
column = atoi(p);
printf("%d, %d\n", row, column);
```

Will have to change to these:

```
*row = atoi(p);
*column = atoi(p);
printf("%d, %d\n", *row, *column);
```

...and so forth...

```
matrix = malloc((*row) * sizeof(double*));
for (j = 0; j < *row; ++j) {
```

---

I will proceed debugging the question source upon request.

Comment: I changed it and here is my new code, I changed the fillAndCheckMatrice():

Comment: I get the segmentation fault and i believe it it on the pthread_create but I dont see the error

Comment: c99. Dont u get a segmentation fault? @Mahonri

Comment: I am not using a compiler... just my brain.  (I've been doing C programming for a very long time.)  I would like to know what compiler you are using so that I can suggest how to best debug your seg-fault.  For example, if you are using gcc, I can help you use gdb to locate where the segfault is -exactly-.

Comment: I am working on a mac and I am using gcc cuz it works better. But I don't know why I have the feeling that at the pthrea_create method sth is not as it must be

Comment: @jumetaj, gcc on a mac is fine.  I have often used that environment myself.  Have you used gdb previously?

Comment: Well yes but I have it on the Uni laboratory

Comment: (Sorry... I am unfamiliar with 'Uni Laboratory) Assuming that you are able to run gdb, and assuming that the name of your executable is "test', try the following command: gdb ./test

Comment: Ok i will try it and then post it